# ElasticSearch JDBC River for SQL Server 2012 enterprise

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch

I am having issues with using JDBC Driver for ElasticSearch River to feed data from SQL Server 2012 enterprise.

Here is my setup:

- OS : Windows 2008 R2 X64
- ES : 1.2.1
- JDK : jdk-7u60-windows-x64
- JRE : jre-7u60-windows-x64
- Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server

When I ran the jdbc to feed the data into ES i got the below exception:

---

`C:\Users\madhavan.ram>curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/orders/order/_meta' -d' {"type": "jdbc", "jdbc": {"driver
": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver","url": "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=adventureworks", "user":"sa","password":"password",
"sql": "SELECT * From [orders]","index": "orders","type": "order","bulk_size": 100,"max_retries": 5,"max_retries_wait": "30s","max_bulk_requests": 5,"bulk_flush_interval": "5s"}}'
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 83
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: *
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: From
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 6`

---

It looks like MSSQL 4.0 driver does not support JDK 1.7. But If i configure the JAVA_Home to JDK 1.6.. ES does not work on windows. Is there a better way to load data from SQL Server 2012 to ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old but now **Elastic Search** can be easily setup on **Windows** with **SQL Server**.

Rivers has been deprecated:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating-rivers

So you should use elasticsearch-jdbc plugin:

https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc

And set it up with JDBC importer in feeder mode.

Basically, once you installed **Elastic Search** and **elasticsearch-jdbc** plugin:

1. Download and install JDBC SQL Server Driver from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774
2. Create **jdbc_sqlserver.json**

   ```
   {
      "type":"jdbc",
      "jdbc":{
         "url":"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test",
         "user":"test",
         "password":"test",
         "sql":"SELECT id as _id, id, name FROM planets",
         "index":"planets",
         "type":"planet",
         "autocommit":"true"
      }
   }
   ```
3. Create **jdb_sqlserver.ps1** file with this content:

   ```
   function Get-PSVersion {
       if (test-path variable:psversiontable) {$psversiontable.psversion} else {[version]"1.0.0.0"}
   }
   $powershell = Get-PSVersion
   if($powershell.Major -le 2 ){
       Write-Error "Oh, so sorry, this script requires Powershell 3 (due to convertto-json)"
       exit
   }
   if((Test-Path   env:\JAVA_HOME) -eq $false){
       Write-Error "Environment variable JAVA_HOME must be set to your java home"
       exit
   }
   $DIR = "D:\programs\elasticsearch\plugins\elasticsearch-jdbc-1.7.0.1\"
   $FEEDER_CLASSPATH="$DIR\lib"
   $FEEDER_LOGGER="file://$DIR\bin\log4j2.xml"
   java -cp "$FEEDER_CLASSPATH\*" -"Dlog4j.configurationFile=$FEEDER_LOGGER" "org.xbib.tools.Runner" "org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter" jdbc_sqlserver.json
   ```
4. Run it from **Powershell**
5. `.\jdbc_sqlserver.ps1`

Described a complete setup here:
http://r2d2.cc/2015/08/05/elastic-search-on-windows-with-mysql-sql-server-2014-and-import-feeder/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have installed the jdbc plugin, if not, follow instructions here: https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc actually you can find almost everything you need to setup a river in this page.

rivers are put in a special index called _river, not your document index /orders.

Thus, if you use Sense (now in Marvel), something like below would work:

```
PUT /_river/glacgrp_river/_meta
{
"type":"jdbc",
"jdbc": {
    "driver":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", 
    "url":"jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=SAMLTD",
    "user":"sa","password":"sa",
    "sql":"select RTRIM(LTRIM(ACCTGRPCOD)) as id, RTRIM(LTRIM(ACCTGRPDES)) as descp from [GLACGRP]",
    "strategy" : "poll",
    "schedule":"0/10 * * * * ?",
    "index":"accountgroup",
    "type":"ag",
    "maxbulkactions":500
```

}
}

You can change the database name, table names and other options to your need to try.

after this, you can use GET /_river/your_river_name/_status to check if the river has been setup.

then restart ES, your river should start to automatically fetch data from database and index them!

Hope this helps

Comment: {"took":30,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":2,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"orders","_type":"order","_id":"s21t3YGNSAO7c-pA2Eo9pA","_score":1.0,"_source":{"type": "jdbc", "jdbc": {"driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver","url": "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;Trusted_Connection=yes;databaseName=adventureworks","sql": "select * from [orders]","poll": "10m","strategy": "simple","index": "orders","type": "order","bulk_size": 100,"max_retries": 5,"max_retries_wait": "30s","max_bulk_requests": 5,"bulk_flush_interval": "5s"}}

Comment: Did you successfully set up a river? use GET /_river/your_river_name/_status to check and post here. cheers

Comment: and also, notice that the "poll" parameter is no longer supported by the jdbc plugin. so you can't use "poll":"10m". to specify how often you wanna fetch data from the database, use "schedule" parameter instead. btw, bulk_size and bulk_flush_interval are Obsolete parameters, too. read https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc carefully.